# Orientation Stuck on Landscape

Tags: gnome, display, xrandr

I have a new HP Envy x360 and I'm unable to switch my screens orientation. GNOME doesn't seem to detect that I can flip my display nor can I manually flip my display. I've tried:

```
sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

and then changing the setting in GNOME displays section but I will click on orientation change it to landscape inverted and it would ask if I wanted to keep the changes (but the screen was still normal landscape) hitting keep changes would send me back to display screen where it would show the orientation as Landscape still. I tried using xrandr

```
xrandr -o inverted --verbose
```

```
 SZ:    Pixels          Physical       Refresh
*0   1920 x 1080   ( 508mm x 286mm )  *77  
Current rotation - normal
Current reflection - none
Rotations possible - normal 
Reflections possible - none
Setting size to 0, rotation to inverted
Setting reflection on neither axis
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

I tried to find the exact name of the display using

```
xrandr -q --verbose
```

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x39f) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x39e
    Timestamp:  51295
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x39f) 159.667MHz *current
        h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

I tried using the dnconf-editor to see if I could change things that way but that didn't work

I double checked the settings with gsettings and got this

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr
```

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup 'follow-lid'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-configuration-file '/org/gnome-settings-daemon/xrandr/monitors.xml'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active true
```

and

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen
```

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock false
```

and

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.remote-display
```

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.remote-display priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.remote-display active true
```

and reinstalling iio-sensor-proxy throughout these steps and many different variations of this. Any and all ideas appreciated

Comment: You have not said what flavour of Ubuntu you are running or which version/kernel etc. Update your question to add those details so people have more information to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amd ryzen 7 4000u processors with integrated radeon graphics isn't supported in the 5.4 linux kernel. upgrading to 5.6 solves the issue. doesn't support auto rotate but keyboard shortcuts can be made to make it work, the brightness of the screen might be too bright after doing this. I suggest using brightness-controller to fix this issue. This solution works on ubuntu 20.04 and popOS 20.04.

check your kernel version with

```
uname -r
```

you'll need 5.6 or later

go to [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)
download the header, image, and modules .deb files you need (you probably don't need low latency unless you're doing audio recording)

I suggest copying them into their own folder and then running

```
sudo dpkg –i *.deb
```

this should solve the problem. If you also have monitor brightness problems you can install brightness-controller to solve that

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```